# How to put out apk file uses gradle v4.1 in Android Studio 3.0+?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I want to set APK filePath in gradle that version is v4.1,but I can set its name and not set file path. What do I do?

```
applicationVariants.all {
    variant->
        variant.outputs.all {
            output->
                def outputFile = output.outputFile
                if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk')) {
                    outputFileName = "${defaultConfig.applicationId}_${variant.productFlavors[0].name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}_${releaseTime()}.apk"
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error logs? and where did you call applicationVariants.all { } in gradle?

Comment: I don't have error logs, and it is running successful. I want to know How to set custom app folders in gradle v4.1 .

Comment: I've posted the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out solution for this:

```
applicationVariants.all{
            variant->
                //Android Studio 3.0+
                variant.outputs.all{
                    outputFileName = "${defaultConfig.applicationId}_${variant.productFlavors[0].name}_${defaultConfig.versionName}_${releaseTime()}.apk"
                    variant.packageApplication.outputDirectory = new File("xx/yyy/ttt")

                }
        }
```

But It may be deprecated in gradle 5.0+，because `variant.packageApplication.outputDirectory` will be deleted in gradle 5.0. And you see a warning that: `access outputDirectory exceeds its access rights`

Comment: Thanks @nhoxbypass.

Answer (score 1):

From this [migration guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output),

> Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the
>   new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK
>   name during build time.
>
> However, more complicated tasks that involve accessing outputFile
>   objects no longer work. That's because variant-specific tasks are no
>   longer created during the configuration stage.

What you already achieved is the ONLY thing that we can do with APK at build time.

You can workaround by moving the files to another location after build completion using [Gradle copy task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files):

```
task copySupportFiles(type: Copy){
    from 'src/main/support'
    into 'build/outputs/apk'
    include '**/*.dat'
    include '**/.txt'
}

assembleDebug {}.doLast{
    tasks.copySupportFiles.execute()
}
```

Comment: First,thanks you answer.  I see some blogs about it .That  create a array that add the folder,then foreach fileArray,copy to a new folder . Fortunately, I found a better method.

Comment: @Mr.Four which one? can you share it with me? But my answer is working right?

Comment: I have posted the method ,but it may be deprecated in gradle 5.0+.